# Set timestamp of message in logstash based on JMSActiveMQBrokerInTime

Tags: jms, logstash, activemq-classic

Currently our logstash is configured to use `JMSTimestamp` as `@timestamp`.

```
jms {
     use_jms_timestamp => true
```

But this causes problems when messages are sent from multiple servers. If clocks are not synchronized ordering of messages is wrong.

Docs say there is `JMSActiveMQBrokerInTime` property which holds Time stamp (in milliseconds) for when the message arrived at the broker.

When I switch configuration of jms plugin to not use `JMSTimestamp` then `@timestamp` is set based on time logstash picked message from queue. This will give me ordering but times will be off when for example logstash is stopped for few minutes.

How can I use `JMSActiveMQBrokerInTime` as `@timestamp`?

I'm running local instance of logstash with this configuration

```
input {

jms {
     include_header => true
     include_properties => true
     include_body => true
     interval => 10
     use_jms_timestamp => false
     destination => "local-logstash-input"
     yaml_file => "c:\dev\elk\tests\local_jmsMQ.yml"
     yaml_section => "activemq"
 }
}

output {
  stdout {
      codec => json
  }
}
```

and I don't see this property in output.

Comment: Can you give an example of value in the `JMSActiveMQBrokerInTime` field?

Comment: It's a number. Time stamp (in milliseconds) for when the message arrived at the broker. https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties

Comment: You can use a `date` filter to use any date/time field as the `@timestamp` field, I think that your field would match the pattern UNIX_MS, which parse epoch values.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) for examples.

Comment: But I don't see this field in output. Like a mentioned.